# Android Srtudio Glide cannot load Image?

Tags: java, android-studio

[image]

```
package com.zj.cjrkos;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adater_pemilik extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adater_pemilik.ViewHolder>  {
    private ArrayList<Upload> entriesi;
    private Context Ctx;
    public Adater_pemilik(ArrayList<Upload> entrie, Context ctx) {
        this.entriesi = entrie;
      Ctx = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public Adater_pemilik.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fotokosku,parent,false);
        Adater_pemilik.ViewHolder vi = new Adater_pemilik.ViewHolder(v);

        return vi;
        //return new ViewHolder(V);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adater_pemilik.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        final String nama = entriesi.get(position).getName();
        final String hah=entriesi.get(position).getPhoto();
       Glide.with(Ctx)
               .load(hah)
               .into(holder.fot);

       holder.nmfoto.setText(nama);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return entriesi.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private FirebaseAuth auth;
        TextView nmfoto;
        ImageView fot;

        public ViewHolder(View V) {
            super(V);
            nmfoto= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtkosku);
            fot= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewfotokos);

        }
    }

}
```

and error display

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load on a null Context
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:84)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:629)
    at com.zj.cjrkos.Adater_pemilik.onBindViewHolder(Adater_pemilik.java:40)
    at com.zj.cjrkos.Adater_pemilik.onBindViewHolder(Adater_pemilik.java:16)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1286)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:342)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2793)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1418)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1296)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6631)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDis
```

Comment: Code is text. Don't post it as an image.

Comment: `Ctx` is null, you never initialize it.

Comment: how do i initialize it

Answer (score 1):

Your `Ctx` is null. You should give a valid `Context` object, either from an Activity or a View.

You can try this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adater_pemilik.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

   ......
   Glide.with(holder.fot.getContext())   // Change this line
           .load(hah)
           .into(holder.fot);

   .....

}
```